# Reset stack inside a tab on tab double press using React Navigation 5

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am wondering how to reset a stack inside a BottomTabNavigator if the Tab is focused and pressed.

**This is the code I have so far:**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<MainStackParams>()
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabNavigatorParams>()
const navigationRef = React.useRef()

> Blockquote

<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
    <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
            <Stack.Screen
                name={MainAppRoute.BOTTOM_TAB_NAVIGATOR}
                component={BottomTabNavigator}
            />
            ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

function BottomTabNavigator() {
    return (
        <BottomTab.Navigator>
            <BottomTab.Screen
                name={TabNavigatorRoute.SOME_STACK}
                component={SomeStack}
                listeners={{tabPress: e => {

                    // TODO: Reset stack in current tab (unsure how to do this)

                }}}
            />
            ...
        </BottomTab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

In the TODO (in the code snippet) the following should probably be done:

- Get navigationRef from app NavigationContainer
- Check if the selected BottomTab is focused (to determine a double press)

  - e.preventDefault
  - reset `SomeStack` (unsure how to get the navigation object a stack inside a BottomTabNavigator)

Have any one been able to do this yet? 
Appreciate all answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Okey, basically you have 2 options to manage this, first is to check navigation state, but as i found out, it works only on IOS device, android does not do anything.

This piece of code navigated to first screen from this stacknavigator

```
<Tab.Screen name={`DeviceNavigatorTab`} component={DeviceNavigator} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Image source={require('../../images/feather_home-menu.png')} style={{width: 26, height: 26, tintColor}}/>,
        }} listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            tabPress: e => {
                if (route.state && route.state.routeNames.length > 0) {
                    navigation.navigate('Device')
                }
            },
        })} />
```

The other solution, and even better, works on android and IOS operating systems

> DeviceNavigatorTab this is tab navigator screen name, {screen: 'Device'} is the first stack screen name in sub stack navigator, hope it helps

```
<Tab.Screen name={`DeviceNavigatorTab`} component={DeviceNavigator} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Image source={require('../../images/feather_home-menu.png')} style={{width: 26, height: 26, tintColor}}/>,
        }} listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
            tabPress: e => {
                navigation.navigate('DeviceNavigatorTab', { screen: 'Device' });
            },
        })} />
```

It is not actually resetting the navigators, it just goes to specified screen inside that tab navigator.

Comment: Thank you Karli. I have been looking everywhere for this (2 days straight). I would prefer a reset, but this option will work until I can find a way to reset this

Comment: I found an solution to resetting stack navigators, so you cant go back on an certain screen, this will reset stack to 2 routes and will go to second screen and you can go from there to home only, hope it helps

this.props.navigation.reset({
                index: 1,
                routes: [{name: Route.HOME}, { name: Route.VEHICLE_PENALTY_PRINT, params: { fine: data, carNr } }]
            });